Wired internet suddenly extremely slow
I've been complaining for some time on slow response from browsers and other things connected, but never suspected connection speed. Finally checked it and it turned up 1-5 Mbit/s. On all other computers I have 200-300.
Unplugged the cable and plugged it into a windows computer, got 250 Mbit/s. So not cable.
Plugged an ethernet adapter to USB, still the same, a couple of Mbit/s. So, not network card.
Found advice on turning ASPM off in grub file. Added GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="pcie_aspm=off pcie_port_pm=off" to it, did the update-grub, restarted, still no change.
Have done the apt update and apt upgrade. What might be the problem?
Thanks
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

inxi -Nn
Network:
  Device-1: Intel 82578DM Gigabit Network driver: e1000e
  IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: 6c:62:6d:c4:b7:1a
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter type: USB
    driver: r8152
  IF: enxa0cec864e1a3 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full
    mac: a0:ce:c8:64:e1:a3
  IF-ID-1: vpn state: unknown speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A

sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82578DM Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: enp0s25
       version: 05
       serial: 6c:62:6d:c4:b7:1a
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=6.5.0-35-generic firmware=0.12-2 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:24 memory:f0400000-f041ffff memory:f0425000-f0425fff ioport:1100(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 6
       bus info: usb@2:1.8
       logical name: enxa0cec864e1a3
       serial: a0:ce:c8:64:e1:a3
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8152 driverversion=v1.12.13 duplex=full firmware=rtl8153a-4 v2 02/07/20 ip=192.168.10.102 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s

Hardware is:

Hewlett-Packard HP Compaq 8100 Elite SFF PC
8,0 GiB RAM,
Intel® Core™ i5 CPU 650 @ 3.20GHz × 4


Measurements were made from Brave and FireFox browsers.

From System Monitor: CPUs not loaded, memory use 3.5-4 GB, HD 350 of 500 GB available.
